# How to return a file (with description and version) in ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api

I'm trying to create a endpoint in my ASP.NET WebAPI for downloading a file. When I download the file through the endpoint, it loses some properties like description, icon and version.

[image]

I tried to use the most voted methods here in StackOverflow, but none of them worked for me.

My code right now:

```
[HttpGet("Download_File")]
public IActionResult Download_File()
{
     var filePath = $"./myfile.exe";

     var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

     return File(bytes, "application/octet-stream", Path.GetFileName(filePath));
}
```

Comment: Files have no such things by themselves. *Some file types* may include icons or version information, and that is **not** lost when downloading.

Comment: Those could be missing due to MOTW. Check for an “unblock” button in the General tab. Nothing a web server can do if that is the problem.

Comment: Those properties are stored by the operating system in some sort of file allocation table and not in the file itself.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos when I download the file and try to run, it gives my the "this app can't run on your pc" error, although the original file runs without problems.

Comment: @RafaelWille, is the file signed?

Comment: @jdt No. I've just edited those version and descriptions properties.

Comment: @RafaelWille, that is the default behaviour of the Windows Protection system. It will display that message for any executable that you have downloaded that have not been signed with a code signing certificate.

Comment: @RafaelWille so you actually did store them as NTFS properties which are *NOT* stored as path of the executable. They're stored in an alternate stream. In any case you didn't demonstrate a problem yet. You may be returning the wrong file. The file may already be mangled. `return File` is used by thousands of developers, if it was broken people would have noticed a decade ago. Perhaps you return the wrong file because you use a relative path without resolving it. Perhaps the file is simply blocked.

Comment: @RafaelWill, if you click on `More info` and `Run anyway` the executable should run. Clients will unfortunately not like this =)

Comment: Have you tried examining the downloaded file in an editor?  If you are not checking response status (error code) on the client, you might be saving an error message instead of the desired content.

Comment: You can also use `fc <file1> <file2>` to check if both programs are the same.

Comment: The bottom line is that if you want to distribute your Windows-based executable on the Web, you will either need to sign it with a code signing certificate or explain to customers why they are getting all sorts of alerts. I don’t like paying GoDaddy or DigiCert any more than the next guy but that is the unfortunate reality.

Comment: Yeah, i realised that it is more easier to upload the file in GoogleDrive or OneDrive and then downloading it from there. At least it wont give me "block/unblock" problem. Thanks guys for all the knowledge!